# What is "persistent store" in layman terms?

Tags: database, redis

In "redis" documentation there were some terms like in-memory store, persistent store. What are those exactly and why we use them ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- in-memory store implies using RAM like memory which is wiped each time the machine is started up - Usually fast
- persistent is a kind of storage which persists over "sessions" when you shutoff the computer you hard drive persist the data that was saved to it. - Usually slow

Comment: It is worth noting that Redis, in spite of being an in-memory datastore, has tunable data persistency options that allow the data in it to survive restarts.

Comment: In-memory is also usually lost when the process stops. So there are cases when your computer doesn't restart, but an in-memory store can be lost.

Comment: Thank you @CarsonDarling I as actually contemplating how much should I complicate this answer since you can put SQL in the persistent category and so on.Maybe I should explicitly add these are general case

Comment: Indeed in-memory and persistent are not mutually exclusive. In the specific case of Redis the representation of the data to be served and modified by clients queries is in-memory, while the persisted format is only good to reload the state at startup, but can't be efficiently queried if not re-loaded back into memory.